# how to delete a character?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

Hi I am developing a code in which I need to perform a delete a last character from a uitextview
I tried like this

```
-(IBAction)delete:(id)sender{
    uitextview.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",uitextview.text,@"\b"];
}
```

on a delete button action i gave this code but this is not performing the deletion.
please help to doing this work and thanks in advanceO

Comment: user899926 and nik's you are friends or something? Why you repeat right answer and nik's set it as accepted?

Comment: @jamapag I am sorry just tried to accpect more then one answer and i don't know that i cant accpect more then one answer. :)

Comment: I think you need to actually delete the character.  Eg, consider using substring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For remove last character use something like this:

```
-(IBAction)delete:(id)sender{
    uitextview.text =[uitextview.text substringToIndex:[uitextview.text length] - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To remove 1st character from the string try the following:

```
-(IBAction)delete:(id)sender{
    uitextview.text =[uitextview.text substringFromIndex:1];
}
```

To remove last one:

```
-(IBAction)delete:(id)sender{
    uitextview.text = [uitextview.text substringToIndex:[uitextview.text length]-1];
}
```

You may also need to check if your string is not empty otherwise "index out of bounds" exception may occur

Comment: thanks a ton Vladimir But i need to delete to delete the last character of text-view and if i give substringFromIndex:1 its delete the first charter of the sting

Comment: @nik's aha, sorry, typo in your question has made it a bit ambiguous :) edited the answer, although I suppose the credit for it should go to jamapag now

Answer (score 2):

This would work also

```
- (IBAction)delete:(id)sender {

  [uitextview deleteBackward];
}
```

Comment: This is a simple, build-in solution. Much more cleaner than the other solutions!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the substringFromIndex method like so:

```
uitextview.text = [uitextview.text substringFromIndex:1];
```

Make sure to check the length before doing this, else the substringFromIndex call will throw an exception.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringFromIndex:

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([string length] >0)
{
    string = [string SubstringToIndex: [sting length] -1];
}
```

Comment: Ah!  I can hear Scott Joplin playing!!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the above answers, to make a string drop the first character it needs to be

substringfromindex says: make a new string starting at index (1 here) until the end

```
bevNoMoney = [totalBevSales substringFromIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Several answers are susceptible to index out of bounds exceptions. Here is a safer implementation:

```
-(IBAction)delete:(id)sender{
    if (uitextview.text.length > 0) {
        uitextview.text =[uitextview.text substringToIndex:[uitextview.text length] - 1];
    }
}
```